# How to convert this page to xml or view a xml representation of this page?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Say I have this site http://www.motortrend.com/gas_prices/34/98006/, which displays the gas prices for my area. Is there any way to convert this information to xml so I can actually parse and get specific pieces of information from it ?

Comment: You can use Jsoup to scrape the html, and use any kind of regular Views and Layouts to display it however you want.

Comment: They Are not Providing Any RSS related to the Gas Price. You need to go here http://www.opisnet.com/ and find your place and get the RSS.

Comment: @MikeM. Jsoup is html parser will help him for the first 10 records only.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Maybe, but s/he specified that page, and it's obvious they use a `page?.html` format for additional pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can write authors of site, maybe they have open API for you.
In the another way you can use jsoup and parse page by page data.